# Apply conditional formatting to a blank cell if another cell in the row is not blank

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am trying to create a formula for conditional formatting that would highlight a blank cell if another cell in the same row is not blank (i.e., that row is being "used"). The picture below shows that cell `J13` is highlighted red because it is blank, and cell H13 is not. I have applied the following conditional formatting equation to the range `J13:J`.

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(H3:H)),(ISBLANK(J3:J)))
```

Instead of applying a similar formula to each column, I would like a formula that would do this for every cell in the range `I3:AA`, checking whether each cell in this range is blank and checking to see if the corresponding cell in column H is not blank. I thought something like this would work over the range `I3:AA`.

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(H3:H)),(ISBLANK(I3:AA)))
```

But it unfortunately doesn't work.

Can this even work with conditional formatting?

[image: Conditional Formatting Example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula you need is the following:

```
=NOT(ISBLANK($H3))*(ISBLANK(I3))
```

**Please pay attention to the `$` sign in front of `H3`**.
Using the `$` (dollar) sign we "lock" the column and the formatting is being applied on the whole row.
You apply the formula on the range `I3:AA`.

Comment: I see! I knew there was something funky about how referencing worked with conditional formatting, but I totally forgot how it worked. Thanks marikamitsos!